# Need help unpacking this equation. Finite difference form of solution to PDE using Green's function has a cross product symbol in it.

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, partial-differential-equations, vectors, greens-function

I was reading a research paper and I observed the conversion of 2-D integral of Green's Function into its finite form. It used the free space Green's function to solve the following Poisson's Equation: $$\nabla^2 \chi(\textbf{x}) = \alpha(\textbf{x}); \ \ \ \textbf{x} = (x,y)$$. We have the equation for the solution via the free space Green's function as: $$\chi(\textbf{x}) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_D \ln(r)\alpha(\textbf{x}')d\textbf{x}' \ \ \ \ \text{where: } \textbf{x}' = (x',y'),r = \sqrt{(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2}$$. According to the paper, the discrete form of this equation (which I need help unpacking and I'll box it to emphasize its importance) is

$$\boxed{\chi(\textbf{x}_{i.j}) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \sum_p \sum_q \alpha(\textbf{x}_{p,q}) \times \Big(\ln(|p-i,q-j|)+\ln(\delta s)\Big)\delta s^2} \\ \text{where } \delta s = \delta x = \delta y, \text{ and } \textbf{x}_{p,q} = (x_p,y_q) = (p \delta s, q\delta s)$$.

So far what I can assume based on my own knowledge is couple of things.

- First, given from the paper that $\delta s = \delta x = \delta y$, I'm assuming that the term $\delta s^2$ is the finite form of $d\textbf{x}' = dxdy$ which is coming from the Riemann sum equivalent of the integrals.
- Second, that and $\ln(|p-i,q-j|)$ with the use of a comma looks odd to me, but I'm guessing it would be written out as $\ln(\sqrt{(p-i)^2+(q-j)^2})$.
- and Third, that the finite form of r is $\sqrt{(p\Delta x - i\Delta x)^2 + (q\Delta y - j\Delta y)^2} = \sqrt{\big((p-i)^2+(q-j)^2\big)\delta s^2}$ and taking the natural log gives: $\frac{1}{2}\Big(\ln\big((p-i)^2 + (q-j)^2\big)+2\ln(\delta s)\Big)$. Redistributing the $\frac{1}{2}$ gives $\ln(r(\textbf{x}_{p,q})) =  \ln\big(\sqrt{(p-i)^2 + (q-j)^2}\big)+\ln(\delta s) = \ln(|p-i,q-j|)+\ln(\delta s)$.

What's confusing me is that this looks like some vectorized form hence the cross product, however neither are vectors, both are magnitudes. $\alpha$ is actually defined as $\alpha = \nabla \cdot \textbf{V}$ meaning it's a scalar field representing divergence, and we're using r as the scalar distance between $\textbf{x}$ and $\textbf{x}'$ making it a scalar field as well, so unless $\times$ means something else in the finite difference scheme or whatever context might give it a different meaning, I don't understand what this operator is supposed to mean. Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks to me as if it is just regular multiplication.  Maybe the authors just wanted to emphasise that multiplication in particular. Maybe the typesetters at the journal just decided to make it that.

Comment: @messenger honestly that's what I'm thinking too. Perhaps that is why they chose to write it that way. There are several things in the paper which are displayed in a different way than I'm used to, and perhaps this is just another one of them. Thanks!